# How can i get Youtube user feed?

Tags: youtube-api

I found way how ot do it by YouTube API v2 ("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/{USERID}/newsubscriptionvideos"). Can i do same thing with API v3?

Comment: What language do you intend to do this in.  This is a poorly asked question.  v2 is deprecated.  Research.

Comment: and what do you mean by user feed?  You mean watched videos? or uploaded videos?

Answer (score 1):

v2 is deprecated. I've written an equivalent for YouTube API v3 (PHP).

Hopefully this will get you started:

https://gist.github.com/LimeSap/ef0ff18884be2e2fd009

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with [activities.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list) with home=true